# Bottom Navigation Bar In Flutter Gives An Error

Tags: flutter, navigationbar

The bottom navigation bar does not navigate to other pages when a tab is selected.

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

```
 int myIndex = 0;
  List<Widget> widgetList = [
    homepage1(),
    video(),
  ];


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Know Zulu Now'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      ),
     bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
       onTap: (index){
         setState(() {
           myIndex = index;
         });
       },
       currentIndex: myIndex,
       items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home),
           label: "Home",
                ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.video_file),
           label: "Video,
         ),
       ],
     ),
     body: Center(
       child: widgetList[myIndex],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error message I get is below:

The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Duplicate Global Key detected in widget tree.

The following Global Key was specified multiple times in the widget tree. This will lead to parts of the widget tree being truncated unexpectedly, because the second time a key is seen, the previous instance is moved to the new location. The key was:

- [GlobalKey#7b93b]
  This was determined by noticing that after the widget with the above global key was moved out of its previous parent, that previous parent never updated during this frame, meaning that it either did not update at all or updated before the widget was moved, in either case implying that it still thinks that it should have a child with that global key.
  The specific parent that did not update after having one or more children forcibly removed due to Global Key reparenting is:
- Ignore Pointer(ignoring: false, render Object: RenderIgnorePointer#efbd4 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE DETACHED)
  A Global Key can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
  When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
  #0      Build Owner. finalize Tree. (package: flutter/s r c/widgets/framework.dart:2991:15)
  #1      Build Owner . finalize Tree (package: flutter/s r c/widgets/framework.dart:3016:8)
  #2      Widgets Binding . draw Frame (package: flutter/s r c/widgets/binding.dart:893:19)
  #3      Renderer Binding. _handle Persistent Frame Call back (package: flutter/s r c/rendering/binding.dart:370:5)
  #4      Scheduler Binding. _invoke Frame Call back (package: flutter/s r c/scheduler/binding.dart:1146:15)
  #5      Scheduler Binding. handle Draw Frame (package: flutter/s r c/scheduler/binding.dart:1083:9)
  #6      Schedule Binding. _handle  Draw Frame (package: flutter/s r c/scheduler/binding.dart:997:5)
  #10     _invoke (dart: u i/hooks.dart:151:10)
  #11     Platform Dispatcher. _draw Frame (dart: u i/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
  #12     _draw Frame (dart: u i/hooks.dart:115:31)
  (elided 3 frames from dart: async)
  ====================================================================================================

I upgraded flutter and still the error persists.

Comment: Please share what's 2 pages (homepage1() & video(),) contains